# При запуске Appium выдает Non-default server args:

Tags: тестирование, appium

При запуске Appium выдает:

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.0
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   relaxedSecurityEnabled: true
[Appium]   allowInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium]   denyInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
```

И я не могу войти в New Session Window.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается Appium работает, это не ошибка, а New Session Window вроде уже не поддерживается.